# Bash script count down 5 minutes display on single line

Tags: bash

I would like to have a count down of 5 minutes, updating every second and showing the result on the same line. Is this even possible with Bash scripting?

Comment: What does the countdown do? You need to be a little more specific about the whole thing.

Comment: This is absolutely possible. If you tell us why (what actual system/network administration problem you're trying to solve) we can tell you which of the many available methods to do it will likely work best for you. If it's a general "How do I do this in a `bash` script?` question your question is probably better suited to [unix.se] -- let me know and I can migrate it there for you :)

Comment: Here's a way https://github.com/himanshub16/MyScripts/blob/master/countdown.sh

Answer (score 61):

This works from Bash shell:

```
secs=$((5 * 60))
while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne "$secs\033[0K\r"
   sleep 1
   : $((secs--))
done
```

The special character **\033[0K** represents an end of line which cleans the rest of line if there are any characters left from previous output and **\r** is a carriage return which moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. There is a nice thread about this feature at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628327/how-to-show-and-update-echo-on-same-line).

You can add own commands or whatever in the while loop. If you need something more specific please provide me more details.

Comment: Do you mean \033[K as per http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php instead of 0K?

Comment: I put `\r` at the beginning to put cursor at the end of line (which prevent it to hide the first character).

Here is the updated version: https://gist.github.com/boillodmanuel/676b3af823fae4177f1d0b41a6f23442

Thanks

Comment: Note for anyone confused by the leading colon on line 5: That is the null operator, allowing the following `$((...))` construction to be evaluated without being interpreted as a command. However, I believe the same effect can be had more simply by just putting `((secs--))` in place of `: $((secs--))`.

Comment: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "secs--"

Answer (score 15):

Here's one with an improvement of right output format (HH:MM:SS) with proper leading zeros and supporting hours:

```
#!/bin/bash

m=${1}-1 # add minus 1 

Floor () {
  DIVIDEND=${1}
  DIVISOR=${2}
  RESULT=$(( ( ${DIVIDEND} - ( ${DIVIDEND} % ${DIVISOR}) )/${DIVISOR} ))
  echo ${RESULT}
}

Timecount(){
        s=${1}
        HOUR=$( Floor ${s} 60/60 )
        s=$((${s}-(60*60*${HOUR})))
        MIN=$( Floor ${s} 60 )
        SEC=$((${s}-60*${MIN}))
     while [ $HOUR -ge 0 ]; do
        while [ $MIN -ge 0 ]; do
                while [ $SEC -ge 0 ]; do
                        printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\033[0K\r" $HOUR $MIN $SEC
                        SEC=$((SEC-1))
                        sleep 1
                done
                SEC=59
                MIN=$((MIN-1))
        done
        MIN=59
        HOUR=$((HOUR-1))
     done
}

Timecount $m
```

Gives an output that looks like this:

```
02:04:15
```

Comment: The output isn't quite `HH:MM:SS`.  For single digit minutes or seconds, you could see `00:4:5`.